# Truncate/Delete the log file contents which are generated via output redirection ">"

Tags: bash, shell, file, truncate

Issue is, all the below listed commands make the file size 0 (Zero) but for some time.
When the new logs are generated then **log file size is =** **old file size(before truncate) + new log messages size**.
This means that truncate **does not free the disk space** occupied by the file.
File size should be whatever the size of new log messages those are coming after truncate command.

I have tried below options before asking this question.

> 1. $ > sysout.log
> 2. $ : > sysout.log
> 3. $ cat /dev/null > sysout.log
> 4. $ cp /dev/null sysout.log
> 5. $ dd if=/dev/null of=sysout.log
> 6. $ echo "" > sysout.log
> 7. $ echo -n "" > sysout.log
> 8. $ truncate -s 0 sysout.log

At first, I checked the file size (contains **10 lines** of log messages)

> [root@mylaptop ~]# ls -lh sysout.log
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root **6.0K** Dec  2 11:30 sysout.log

Then ran the *truncate* command

> [root@mylaptop ~]# truncate -s0 sysout.log
>   [root@mylaptop ~]# ls -lh sysout.log
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root **0** Dec  2 11:31 sysout.log

After few seconds **2 lines** of log messages printed into the file. But file size is

> [root@mylaptop ~]# ls -lh sysout.log
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root **6.3K** Dec  2 11:31 sysout.log

As you can see, it adds the file size.
How to free the disk space? Or is there any another approach?

Comment: If a process is keep running(may be a daemon process) then these logs will be keep filling. How about either using a log rotate mechanism? Or you could write the same commands in script form and place them in crontab for scheduled run then.

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh13, Yes I am going to write a crontab for this. But issue is, I want to check the file size, if it's greater than 5GB then copy the logs to S3 and then truncate the file. Here, after truncate it does not release the file size then after certain time job will copy file to S3 very frequently. Please tell me about log rotate mechanism.

Comment: @AniketKulkarni : In case there is *no* other process having the log file open and keeps feeding it, I can not reproduce the effect. For instance, I did a `ls > out.txt; truncate -s 0 out.txt; touch out.txt; echo abc >>out.txt`, the file out.txt contains only _abc_, nothing else.

Comment: @user1934428: The file is created by command: "java - jar my_app.jar > sysout.log 2>&1 &". So it is continuously getting the data.

Comment: For every log you want to manage, you have to check the daemon generating it; to that daemon you can (often) send a signal to tell it "restart your log". You must consult the daemon docs. Logrotate is a mechanism implementing this.

Comment: @linuxfan: thanks. can you provide some reference URLs? That would be helpful. I will read and implement.

Comment: googled for "logrotate explained" and came up with this: https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/understanding-logrotate-utility/  (it's just a starting point anyway, search more!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For long running processes that open the file for write mode (using '>', or otherwise), the process tracks the offset of the next write. Even if the file size is truncated to 0, the next write will resume at the last location. Most likely, based on description is that the long running process continue to log at the old offset (effectively leaving lot of zero-byte data in the start of the file.

- Verify by inspecting the file - did the initial content disappear ?

Solution is simple, instead of logging in `write` mode, use `append` mode.

```
# Start with a clean file
rm -f sysout.log
# Force Append mode.
java - jar my_app.jar >> sysout.log 2>>&1 &

... 
truncate ...
# New data should be written to the START of the file, based on truncated size.
```

Notice that all writing processes, and connections should use `append` mode.

Comment: Solution worked. Thanks for the explanation over `write` and `append`.